# SQL - converting table returned from USER DEFINED FUNCTION to array

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that takes a space-delimited string and returns a table containing rows the individual strings. Something like this:

```
SplitTextReturnTable('Emmanuel John Ahmed', ' ')
```

`// returns a table containing three rows having Emmanuel, John and Ahmed.`

What I want to do is use each of the returned string to perform a search in a table to retrieve rows with data matching the strings, something similar to a for-each-statement that searches the table with each of the returned strings. Here is a pseudo code of what I want.

```
DECLARE @myArray ARRAY;
SET @myArray = ConvertToArray(SplitTextReturnTable('Emmanuel John Ahmed', ' '))
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customers.Fullname LIKE + '%' + @myArray[0] + '%' or Customers.Fullname LIKE + '%' + @myArray[1] + '%' or Customers.Fullname LIKE + '%' + @myArray[2] + '%'
```

Any help would be appreciated. I would also like to know if there's a better way to perform database searching more effectively.

Thanks.

Comment: I see you have edited to say that your function does actually return 3 rows. In that case you just need to join as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why does your `split` function only return one row for this input? It doesn't seem to be splitting at all! What you probably want it to do is to fix it to return a table with 3 rows that you can then join on. i.e. something like

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Customers c
JOIN dbo.SplitTextReturnTable('Emmanuel John Ahmed', ' ') s
ON c.Fullname LIKE '%' + s.value + '%'
```

Regarding the second part of your question you might want to investigate Full Text Search. `LIKE` with leading wildcards is inherently slow.

Comment: thanks Martin.Is there any way to use FullTextSearch with SQL SERVER 2005 EXPRESS Edition? Any link to resources and tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Tobechukwu - Yes you can. You need to download the version with Advanced Services though. It doesn't come bundled with the other edition. I don't know of any particularly good resources in this area but its quite easy to set up full text indexing via a wizard and google should have plenty of stuff.